# Summing RMS values

Tags: audio, signal-processing

Is it possible to sum the RMS values of two (or more) arbitrary waveforms in such a way as to get the RMS value of the combined waveforms?

For example, if I have two rms values calculated from two waveforms:

```
rms_a = sqrt( ( a1^2 + a2^2 + ... + aN^2 ) / N )
rms_b = sqrt( ( b1^2 + b2^2 + ... + bN^2 ) / N )

rms_c = sqrt( ( (a1+b1)^2 + (a2+b2)^2 + ... + (aN+bN)^2 ) / N )
```

Is it possible to combine rms_1 and rms_2 in some way as to arrive at the same or similar value as rms_c, the RMS of the combined waveform?

```
rms_c = function(rms_a, rms_b)
```

You *can* do it for simple waveforms by taking the root of the sum of the squares of the component RMS values:

```
rms_c = sqrt( rms_a^2 + rms_b^2 )
```

...but that doesn't appear to work well for recorded audio.  It's *pretty* close, but there's occasional big differences.

Comment: You're better off asking this on https://dsp.stackexchange.com, but in general you cannot add the RMS values. Consider the two waveforms `sin(ft)` and `sin(ft+p)`, where `p` is a fixed phase offset. If `p = pi`, the two waveforms will be out of phase and will sum to 0. If `p = 0`, the two waveforms will have double the peak amplitude and (in this case) double the RMS energy.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I thought.  I was more after a good-enough-mostly-works-with-recorded-audio solution.  I'll ask over there.  Thanks.  :)

Comment: The new question I asked is here, for anyone stumbling across this in a search: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/63836/summing-rms-values

Answer (score 1):

Consider two sine waves of equal magnitude and frequency, but 180 degrees out of phase.

The sum of their RMS values is simply twice the RMS value of either sine wave.

The sum of the two sine waves together is zero, which has an RMS value of zero.

Therefore, it is not guaranteed that the RMS of the sum is equal to the sum of the RMS values.